# MySQL Workbench 6.3 Can't Create Columns

Tags: mysql

As the question says, I'm simply not able to create or edit columns in MySQL Workbench. I've tried reinstalling, even installing the 32bit version instead of the 64. I have Googled it but it seems like I'm the only one with this problem.

I can create tables with the templates but I need to be able to work with them and then edit them.

In the picture, you can see that the table has a Primary Key and the "Column Name" box is grey and unclickable.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this has been open long enough. I wasn't able to fix the problem however I did find a workaround. If anyone has a similar problem the way I fixed this was by downloading an older version of Workbench. I downloaded version 5.2 and it worked perfectly. Here is the link:

https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/workbench/

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. I guess this is the best solution we've got. Pretty big bug IMHO.

Comment: Well! Version 5.2 let me add any column I wanted, as long as it was an INT. Everything else, such as CHAR, VARCHAR, and DECIMAL, was rejected. I think I need to find a new Entity Relationship modeller :-(

Answer (score 0):

This might come a bit late, but I just had the same problem on build 6.3.5 and found this post.

I also found the real reason and another workaround [on MySQL website](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/workbench/en/wb-news-6-3-6.html), so I thought I would share :

> On Windows 10, and with resolutions of 1366x768 and below, the default
>   table editor window did not show the table columns.
>
> As a workaround, the output pane could be resized or hidden.

This was fixed in build 6.3.6